# A non-third-party way to get emails from a shared mailbox in c#

Tags: c#, email

I've been trying for the past week or so now to find a way to connect to a shared mailbox (server side only, so no outlook) and get emails from the inbox.  I need to input them into a SQL table, which I already completed and figured out.

I just need to find a safe, and secure way to get the emails from the shared mailbox, so no third party libraries/packages.

Any and all responses are greatly appreciated.

Comment: "shared mailbox" is quite unspecific. There are plenty of questions about using, say, SMTP or IMAP/POP3 to send and get email. Have done any research into the native SMTP or IMAP/POP capabilities in .NET?

Comment: No I haven't, as I wasn't sure really what to search too much. 
I saw that SmptClient is obsolete, and AE.Net.Mail hasn't been updated in 5 years.  Do you think MailKit would work?

Comment: No idea, and you've specified "no third party libraries/packages" in your question. Which is good, since recommendation questions are off-topic. But if you explain what you're trying to do in more detail, the research you've done into native .NET capabilities around mail retrieval, answerers are free to offer libraries as part of an answer.

Comment: I have a shared mailbox that I need to extract emails from the inbox and then run a SQL query to add the all emails not already present to a table.  All of this needs to be done in C#

Comment: Where's that shared mail box ? On a corporate Exchange Server ? On a Gmail account ? Somewhere else ? You have to tell more precisely what you want.

Comment: Corporate exchange server.  Sorry for the lack of details, I'm new to dealing with this stuff.